# How to load thumbnail in ListView in a fast way?

Tags: android, performance, listview, android-listview

I wanted to load list of thumbnails of local medias(video files).  I used `ListView` and `Adapter`. And use the `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(uri, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND)` in the method 'getView' to get the thumbnail(get the bitmap then use the ImageView.setImageBitmap). And it worked.
The problem is that it performed very bad. It's not fluency. I tried [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). It still not worked for me. I always get error which said that something wrong happened when decode the `Uri`. I tried to use `Runnable` to deal with it. Fail again.
So is there a demo to deal with the async way to load the thumbnail.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picasso is the best lazy load images library I've ever found !

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: I tried picasso, but I don't know how to get the thumbnail. The api only can support a image url. How can I get a thumbnail from a mp4?

Answer (score 1):

You can use AQuery for Image Loading.

Please visit below link:

https://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Answer (score 1):

you should do it in a new thread, i recommend you to see [SmartImageView](https://github.com/loopj/android-smart-image-view),  and [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) library